# Missing Cactus property [cactus.contextURL]

Tags: java, junit, cactus

I am writing cactus test in eclipse. I have added required jar file.

But When I run my code using RunAs -> JUnit Test, I am getting above error

I have added "cactus.contextURL=http://localhost:8080/test" in cactus.properties file.

Please help me out whats being wrong here

I am getting error as

```
org.apache.cactus.util.ChainedRuntimeException: Missing Cactus property
[cactus.contextURL]
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.configuration.BaseConfiguration.getContextURL(BaseConfiguration.java:59)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.configuration.AbstractWebConfiguration.getRedirectorURL_aroundBody0(AbstractWebConfiguration.java:46)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.configuration.AbstractWebConfiguration.getRedirectorURL_aroundBody1$advice(AbstractWebConfiguration.java:288)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.configuration.AbstractWebConfiguration.getRedirectorURL(AbstractWebConfiguration.java)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.client.connector.http.DefaultHttpClient.callRunTest(DefaultHttpClient.java:159)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.client.connector.http.DefaultHttpClient.doTest_aroundBody0(DefaultHttpClient.java:80)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.client.connector.http.DefaultHttpClient.doTest_aroundBody1$advice(DefaultHttpClient.java:288)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.client.connector.http.DefaultHttpClient.doTest(DefaultHttpClient.java)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.client.connector.http.HttpProtocolHandler.runWebTest(HttpProtocolHandler.java:159)
    at
org.apache.cactus.internal.client.connector.http.HttpProtocolHandler.runTest_aroundBody0(HttpProtocolHandler.java:80)
```

My code is

```
package com.xtremum.taskapplication;

import org.apache.cactus.ServletTestCase;
import org.apache.cactus.WebRequest;
import org.apache.cactus.WebResponse;
import org.junit.Test;


public class CactusServletTest extends ServletTestCase{


public void beginFirst(WebRequest theRequest){

    theRequest.setURL( "localhost:8080", "/CactusTest", "/CactusTestServlet", null, null );
    System.out.println("in setup");
}

public void testFirst() throws Exception {

    assertEquals("Hello Earth!", "ni");
}

public void endFirst(WebResponse theResponse){
    System.out.println("in tear down");
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally solved it by adding following line in beginFirst()

```
System.setProperty("cactus.contextURL","http://localhost:8080/test");
```